# Symfony global and specific prefix controller action

Tags: php, symfony

I have in my file routing.yml configured a prexif for all my route like :

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|es
```

With this, for all my controllers I have a prefix `_locale` like : `/en/buy`, `/en/home`...

I have another controller `AjaxController` and i don't need to use this prefix, but another one : `ajax`.

How can I keep my global prefix `_locale` for all my controllers and use another prefix for just my AjaxController ?

Thanks !

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/P3sKkzn5J-8 - seems you're out of luck at the moment. You could override Router, but that's way more work than simply adding prefix by hand to other routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In symfony routing, the last rule declared is the one which is used by the router. I didn't test it but I guess something like that should be working :

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|es

app_ajax:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/AjaxController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /ajax
```

Once again, I didn't try it ! But i'm pretty sure it's gonna work.
I don't really like these kind of practices in general because it relies upon the router's behaviour, that could be changing through versions…

Comment: Be careful: The Symfony router will always choose the first matching route it finds.

Comment: it will choose the first route matching when a request is analyzed by the router but the router parses the yaml/annotations (or whatever format) before the matching process. And route declarations is read a way that the last declaration wins.

Comment: If the routes had the same name then the last one would probably override it but that would mean that the first route never actually existed. When the router parses the routes it does it in the order that they are provided.

Comment: Ok, in fact this solution is working, my bad :p thanks ! The second routing app_ajax ovveride the first

Comment: This is because your first set of routes only accepts the `_locale` as "en", "fr" or "es". They would work in the other order as well.